# Adding Defer and Async attributes to Script Tags in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mobile, create-react-app

We have this React application created with **Create React App** and now to improve performance we want to include the `SCRIPT` tags (with the Javascript chunks) with the `DEFER` and `ASYNC` attributes.

But these tags are injected automatically by the build process. How do we customize it to allow the `SCRIPT` tags (and eventually the `LINK` tags) of the automatically generated chunks to have the `DEFER` or `ASYNC` directives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would it increase the performance? Wouldn't it be better to lazy-load react components?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski sure. I am splitting the code in smaller chunks, but now I want to control the way it would download blocking scripts

Comment: As i said, lazy-loading https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy